# Git: how to tell if changes in branch exist in another branch

Tags: git

The git model my team uses is short-lived feature branches based off `master` that will get merged into a long-lived `dev` branch for further testing/QA before the pull-request for the feature is merged to master.

I'm trying to write a small script that takes an action based on if the changeset in a feature branch is already in the `dev` branch or not. The issue I've been having is that I don't care about specific commits. If the feature was merged into `dev` then rebased/squashed/etc, the changeset as a whole is in `dev`. And of course the `dev` branch will be getting other features added over time that should be ignored (unless they conflict).

I think the simplest way I can explain the request is; if I were to merge a feature branch into the `dev` branch, would the commit be empty?

I've tried various forms of git diff, branch, merge, and log, but nothing has been quite right. The most accurate working example I have is to checkout `dev`, `merge --no-commit my-feature`, check if any files are in the index, then abort the merge.
But with all the options git offers I refuse to believe there isn't a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the simplest way I can explain the request is; if I were to merge a feature branch into the dev branch, would the commit be empty?

If that's a truly accurate way to measure what you want—and I think it won't be 100% but will be as close as you can get in any sort of automated way—then the way to test this out is to *do* it:

> The most accurate working example I have is to checkout dev, merge --no-commit my-feature, check if any files are in the index, then abort the merge. But with all the options git offers I refuse to believe there isn't a simple way to do this.

There's a technical glitch in the above description: after the merge, there are lots of files in the index.  What you want to check for is whether there are any *nonzero stage* files, indicating a merge conflict, and if not, whether the files in the index *match* those in the *current commit*.

That is, in my opinion, the second-best method.  It works, but it makes it hard to distinguish some potentially-important cases.

The best is to use `git checkout --detach` to do the merge, then do the merge *without* `--no-commit`, but optionally add `--no-ff` (described only in the text below):

```
git checkout --detach dev
git merge <target>         # target can be a hash ID, or a name
```

One of four things can happen at this point:

- The merge fails with a conflict or other issue ("would overwrite untracked files", that sort of thing).

  The exit status of `git merge` is nonzero, which tells you that this is what occurred.  (You could try to inspect text generated *by* `git merge` but there's no real point.)  Use `git merge --abort` or `git reset --merge`—these two commands do exactly the same thing; in fact, one of them runs the other one—to end the merge.
- The merge says "Already up to date" and does nothing.

  The exit status of `git merge` is zero.  The hash ID in `HEAD` is unchanged from what it was before `git merge`.
- The merge says "fast forward" and checks out *`target`*.

  The exit status of `git merge` is zero.  The hash ID in `HEAD` is the hash ID of *`target`* (if you used a hash ID *as* your *`target`*, testing this is extra-easy.)

  Eliminate this option entirely by adding `--no-ff` if you like; in that case you'll get instead the last, fourth option:
- The merge completes OK, creating a new merge commit.

  The exit status of `git merge` is zero.  The hash ID in `HEAD` is the hash ID of a new merge commit.  Its first parent is the hash ID of commit `dev` and its second parent is the hash ID of *`target`*.

You now must check which of these four (or three if using `--no-ff`) cases actually occurred:

1. The first one tells you that the merge is potentially possible but has conflicts, and does require a followup `git merge --abort` (or `git reset --merge`) command.

   This is the case that causes the "won't be 100%": for instance, it happens if your *`target`* was squash-merged, but `dev` has since advanced in an incompatible way.  You can lodge an alert of some sort since this is the test that fails automation.
2. The second tells you that the merge base commit of `dev` / `HEAD` and *`target`* is `HEAD`, i.e., the commit identified by *`target`* is an ancestor of that identified by `dev` ("is the same commit" is considered to be "is ancestor").

   This case means that it's safe, in some sense, to just delete the target branch.
3. The third tells you that the commit identified by `dev` is an ancestor of that identified by *`target`*.  You may want transform this into case 4 using `--no-ff` so as to be able to use the final test below.  However, this tells you that *`target`* is strictly ahead of `dev` (if they were equal, case 2 would have occurred first).
4. The fourth tells you that a clean and simple merge is possible.  You can now check whether the resulting commit *matches* the `dev` commit using:

   ```
   test $(git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}) = $(git rev-parse HEAD^^{tree})
   ```

   If these *don't* match, merging *`target`* would take some change(s) from it.  If they *do* match, merging *`target`* has no effect on the tree.

Because your `HEAD` is detached during this testing process, all you have to do to clean up—other than in case 1 where you must abort the in-progress merge, that is—is `git checkout dev` to re-attach your `HEAD`.  Any commit actually made is now abandoned, and Git will eventually—after 30 days by default—remove it for real.

Comment: I'm going to have to play with this over the next couple of days, but thanks for the insightful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`git cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) command can be used the check which commits in a branch are textually identical to commits in another branch. The first part of the doc is hard to grasp though, therefore take a hard look to the examples section.